# Pointer being freed was not allocated exception at closing brace of autoreleasepool

Tags: objective-c, c

My program is throwing a "pointer being freed was not allocated" error, but the strange part is that it is marking the error as happening on the closing brace of the `@autoreleasepool` within my main method.

I double checked and all of my `free()` calls are deallocating properly, so I'm not sure what it is attempting to free. What might be causing this, or how could I find out?

EDIT:

Here is the exact message:

```
FileCreator(2787,0x7fff7a6de310) malloc: *** error for object 0x10003b000: pointer being freed was not allocated *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

And these are the lines the trace gives me as causing the exception.
In __pthread_kill:

```
0x7fff8f322866:  jae    0x7fff8f322870            ; __pthread_kill + 20
```

Then in (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*)

```
0x7fff8bbfa65a:  cmpq   %r14, 0x10(%r15)
0x7fff8bbfa65e:  jne    0x7fff8bbfa5e1            ; (anonymous namespace)::
```

And finally in main:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        SoundAlignmentDataCreator *creator = [[SoundAlignmentDataCreator alloc] init];
        [creator create : @"320_pac_spa.mp3" : @"/Users/jstrang/Movies/tdata.dat"];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With the closing brace of the autoreleasepool highlighted in main.

Comment: How are `free()` calls related to `@autoreleasepool`? Why are you calling `free()`, are you calling `malloc()`?

Comment: That's why I'm confused. The entire thing executes perfectly fine until everything is done, and when it hits the closing brace of the `@autoreleasepool` I get the "pointer being freed was not allocated" message

Comment: Code and the exception code would help. Add an exception breakpoint. Go to the "Breakpoint Navigator", click on the "+" at the bottom left, select "Add Exception Breakpoint." Run the app to get the breakpoint. When you hit the exception breakpoint click debug continue a couple of times and you will get a backtrace and more error info. Post thatand an exact copy of Xcode/Debugger messages.

Comment: What does "That's why I'm confused." mean? You did not answer my question so it is hard to help.

Comment: And yes, I'm using `malloc()` to create several C arrays, but then I `free()` all of them before the program terminates. The error doesn't happen at any of my `free()` calls, just at the end

Comment: In Xcode go to the scheme and turn on the four Memory Management check boxes. You are over releasing something, ensure that you are not freeing an invalid pointer.

Comment: The error tells you what to do: "set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug". Have you done that?

Comment: Yeah the problem must be that something is being released more than once, but I put a breakpoint at every call to `free()` and none of them cause it

Comment: Are you sure you are only releasing each malloc only once? (That you do not get an exception on the free() does not mean the free should be called. Add the exception breakpoints and see what you get. Turn on the memory management debugging.

Comment: You can also add a `NSLog()` at each `malloc()` and `free()`, include the address in the log message. Then pair them up and verify all are matched.